# Function is Continuous, C is Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis

Define a function $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ by the formula
$f(x)=sup${$f(y):y\in C, y <= x $}. Prove that $f$ is continuous, that $f$ is monotone-increasing and constant on each interval in the complement of $C$, and that $f(1) =1$. $C$ is the Cantor Set.

Comment: Please show us your attempt. If you tell where exactly you have difficulty we can help.

Comment: I am pretty lost generally on how to solve this one. Specifically for x>0, the formula is kinda weird.

Comment: Actually, f can't be continuous which implies it can't be monotone increasing right?

Comment: The function is not well-defined, which is to say that it is not uniquely defined at all. Suppose $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ Then $f$ meets all the conditions. But suppose $f(x)=\sup ([0,x)\cap C)$ for all $x\in [0,1).$ Then $f$ still meets all the conditions, but $f(1)=1.$